# How to force tmux to wait for output from command-prompt?

Tags: configuration, hotkeys, tmux

I would like to create the following binding:

```
unbind r
bind-key r command-prompt -p "Please enter new project name: " "run \"mkdir -p /home/USER/hacking/'%%'\"" \; new-window -c "/home/USER/hacking/%%"
```

Which would (in my mind):

- ask for new project's name and create a folder for it under `/home/USER/hacking/`
- create a new tmux window inside `/home/USER/hacking/NEWLY_PASSED_IN_DIRECTORY`

but it doesn't wait for output from `command-prompt`. It immediately goes to next command and fails (becaus `%%` has not been changed).

How to make it wait for user input?

**EDIT**

Ok, so I have gotten as far as this:

```
bind r command-prompt -p "Please enter new project name: " "new-window -n '%1'" \; run pwd
```

Where I will get the name of new project/directory and after getting user's input I will get a new window in my tmux session but the command is still ran immediately and in current **not new** window.

Comment: Don't know whether you solved this problem or not, but both commands line in you post are working as expected in my environment.